# Updating data source for multiple pivot tables (in different worksheet) within Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Now, I need to update all pivot tables on my Excel worksheet weekly to include the latest data for my report. I have 21 pivot tables on 5 worksheets (call it Report workbook), and the source data is on different worksheets of another workbook (call it Data workbook) which located on a shared drive.

The "Change data source" is not available on my Excel. So I have to manually select on the pivot table and re-select the source data multiple times every week.

Is there an easy way to update the data source for all of my pivot tables at the same time by VBA?

Below is my initial attempt. Thanks.

```
Dim pivotable As PivotTable

For Each pivotable In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("APAC").PivotTables
         pivotable.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
            (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "EC__:weekly report:for EC BU:2017_:Raw data:[Master Raw.xlsx]VOL Total Data!C1:C21")
Next pivotable
```

Comment: **SO** is not a free coding services site, you need to load your code attmempt, show us what you have tried so far, and we will help you. In the meantime, you can use the internet to read about `PivotCache` and how to set it and `Refresh` it.

Comment: So you are addressing un-named cell ranges for your data?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I'm not good at coding, so please forgive me if I broke the regulation. I tried to modify from other's questions, but I can't even update one pivot table. I got "Run-time error -2147483645" every time. It seems that it can't find the shared drive, but I can't find how to make the VBA reference a network location. Thanks again.